# Prisma Python client error querying the shared database: db error: FATAL: SASL authentication failed

Tags: python, prisma

I have a js frontend using Prisma Client JS fine and it works.
I have also a python backend using Prisma Client Python however that errors when i call save_results function with

```
Error querying the database: db error: FATAL: SASL authentication failed
```

They are both pointing to the same schema.prisma file that has 2 generators. One for the JS frontend and one for the python backend.

```
generator python {
  provider = "prisma-client-py"
  interface = "sync"
  recursive_type_depth = 5
}

generator js {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
...
```

I have run the following to connect with the schema

```
prisma generate --generator=python --schema="C:\Users\Simon Palmer\Documents\Programming\ideally\frontend\prisma\schema.prisma"
```

Which confirms connection with

```
Environment variables loaded from ..\..\ideally\frontend\prisma\.env
Prisma schema loaded from ..\..\ideally\frontend\prisma\schema.prisma

✔ Generated Prisma Client Python (v0.8.2) to .\..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\prisma in 241ms
```

The **python setup** is as follows

```
from prisma import Prisma
from prisma.models import User, LotAnalysis
```

then the sync function

```
def save_results(user_id, lot_id) -> None:
    db = Prisma(
        datasource={
            'url': 'postgres://postgres:PASSWORD@db.xdyhoezrrqavppxekqqc.supabase.co:6543/postgres',
        }
    )
    db.connect()
    upload = db.LotAnalysis.update(
        where={
            'lotId': lot_id
      },
    data= {
      'price': 8
      }
    )

    db.disconnect()
```

But i get the error message i mentioned at the start.
If its any help my prisma version is

```
prisma                : 4.11.0
@prisma/client        : Not found
Current platform      : windows
Query Engine (Binary) : query-engine 8fde8fef4033376662cad983758335009d522acb (at ..\..\..\..\.cache\prisma-python\binaries\4.11.0\8fde8fef4033376662cad983758335009d522acb\node_modules\@prisma\engines\query-engine-windows.exe)
Migration Engine      : migration-engine-cli 8fde8fef4033376662cad983758335009d522acb (at ..\..\..\..\.cache\prisma-python\binaries\4.11.0\8fde8fef4033376662cad983758335009d522acb\node_modules\@prisma\engines\migration-engine-windows.exe)
Format Wasm           : @prisma/prisma-fmt-wasm 4.11.0-57.8fde8fef4033376662cad983758335009d522acb
Default Engines Hash  : 8fde8fef4033376662cad983758335009d522acb
Studio                : 0.483.0
```

(Weird it says @prisma/client        : Not found)

Any help would be great!

Comment: I would recommend asking this question here: https://github.com/RobertCraigie/prisma-client-py/discussions so that the library maintainer can help you out.